# Javascript - Manager is a Person but not a Manager itself? Functional/Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to code inheritance with functional/prototypal Inheritance and I created two constructors Person and Manager. Everything sounds fine, but manager is not a Manager object itself. Instead of, it's an Object object. How can I fix this problem?

```
 // <![CDATA[
         var Person = function(name, age)
         {

            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.desc = function()
            {
               return "my name is " + this.name + " I'm " + this.age; 
            }
         }

         var Manager = function(name, age, dept)
         {
            var manager = new Person(name, age);
            manager.dept = dept; 
            manager.mgrDesc = function()
            {
               return manager.desc() + " and I work at the " + manager.dept + " department";
            }

            return manager;
         }

         Manager.prototype = new Person();
         var manager = new Manager("Foo", 3, "IT");
         console.log(manager.mgrDesc());
         console.log(manager instanceof Person);
         console.log(manager instanceof Manager);
       // ]]>
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you're doing inheritance breaks any relationship between the `Manager` function and the objects you're returning from it. You're creating a `Person`:

```
var manager = new Person(name, age);
```

...and then returning that out of your `Manager` function. When you return an object out of your constructor function, it supercedes the object that the `new` operator created for you.

Here's an example of doing this kind of inheritance in JavaScript while keeping that structure intact:

```
var Thing = (function() {
    var p;

    function Thing(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    p = Thing.prototype;

    p.one = one;
    function one() {
        console.log("Thing#one: name = " + this.name);
    }

    p.two = two;
    function two() {
        console.log("Thing#two: name = " + this.name);
    }

    p.three = three;
    function three() {
        console.log("Thing#three: name = " + this.name);
    }

    return Thing;
})();

var NiftyThing = (function(parent) {
    var proxy, p, pp;

    function NiftyThing(name) {
        parent.call(this, name);
    }
    proxy = function() { };
    proxy.prototype = parent.prototype;
    p = new proxy();
    // On ECMAScript5 systems, the three lines above could be
    // replaced with p = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    p.constructor = NiftyThing;
    NiftyThing.prototype = p;
    pp = parent.prototype;

    p.one = one;
    function one() {
        // Call parent
        pp.one.call(this);

        // And also do our own thing
        console.log("NiftyThing#one: name = " + this.name);
    }

    p.two = two;
    function two() {
        // Just do our own thing without calling parent
        console.log("NiftyThing#two: name = " + this.name);
    }

    // We don't override `three`

    return NiftyThing;
})(Thing);
```

Now of course, rather than writing out all of that stuff in `NiftyThing` each time, it's useful to have a helper script that you can reuse. I wrote one called [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs), and in fact the above is part of a [documentation page](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript#3_-_Plain_JavaScript) comparing doing this without and with `Lineage` (this is, of course, the "without" bit). Even if you don't use `Lineage`, that page may be useful in terms of understanding how the plumbing of class-like structures in JavaScript is done.

Obligatory note: It's totally possible to build class-like structures using JavaScript's prototypical inheritance (see above), but note that JavaScript's prototypical inheritance *also* lets you do things with more flexibility. This is one of the things I like about JS: when appropriate, I can do class-like things; when I just need ad hoc "make this object derive from this other object," I can do that, too (using `Object.create`, the *basic* form of which can be shimmed on pre-ECMAScript5 engines).

---

It's worth noting an issue with the code in your question:

You commonly see this anti-pattern, which is in the code above:

```
Manager.prototype = new Person();
```

`Person` is designed to construct instances, not prototypes. Consider, for instance, if `Person` accepted a `name` argument — what name would you pass it when creating the `Manager.prototype` object?

That's why the code above doesn't do that, it does this (using your `Person` and `Manager` as an example):

```
var proxy = function() { };
proxy.prototype = Person.prototype;
Manager.prototype = new proxy();
Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
```

Note that we create a new object that uses `Person.prototype` as its underlying prototype, but *without* calling `new Person()`, so we don't have the issue of what to do if `Person` requires arguments.

Later, when initializing an *instance*, we do the equivalent of this:

```
function Manager() {
    // Init super
    Person.call(this);

    // Do Manager stuff...
}
```

...because at that point, if `Person` needs arguments, we'll have them (either because we supply hard-coded versions, or because `Manager` accepts the arguments).

Comment: @TJC: Although I've glanced at Lineage before, I finally went and had a deeper look.  Very nice.  (Well, that is, if you're into OO, which these days I try hard not to be, preferring functional!  :-)  )  I'm curious as to one documentation decision: why when you want methods with debuggable names do you choose to use references to function expressions rather than named function expressions?  The repetition of the names seems to gain nothing.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: These days, it's just because of [the IE8 problem](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html). Historially, NFEs have been misimplemented in multiple engines, but I think all engines except the one in IE8 and earlier were sorted out years ago. Since the function name inside the function would refer to a *different* function instance than the one on the prototype, that's the reason for the repetition; we rely on information we put on the function instances. Example of the IE8 problem: http://jsbin.com/EnuFOVA/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/EnuFOVA/1/edit)).

Comment: @TJC: Well, yes I've recognized the IE problem for years, and understood it since kangax's great article, but at first glance it just doesn't seem to apply here.  I'm assuming that the function passed into Lineage is run once and the only thing that survives is a closure with references to those functions.  I guess there would be extra memory used for those closures in older IEs with NFE's, but I'm not sure that would be enough to drive me to let the API be less clean.  Of course I don't know how old Lineage is, and how big a factor IE<9 was when you were creating the technique.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: The problem is that Lineage puts information on the function instance that's essential to resolving supercalls correctly. If code within the function uses the standalone reference it gets for the function, that won't be the same function Lineage stores the information on. E.g., in the `var f = function foo(){};` scenario, Lineage uses `f`, but if someone writing code in `foo` uses `foo`, there may be a problem, they aren't the same instance. But let's be clear: This isn't an API thing. You don't have to use named functions at all with Lineage. I just do so in the examples.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: For instance, [this example](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript#5_-_Lineage) showing how to do it without. On modern engines, those functions will actually end up be treated as though they had names (and that's making its way into the next spec). Basically if you assign an anonymous function expression to a variable or property whose name can be resolved at (waves hands) the relevant time, that property or variable name ends up being the name of the function. Very cool. Happened to run across that in the draft spec the other day.

Comment: @TJC: I was thinking more along the lines of `p.f = function foo(){}`, and the only place where there should be a reference to `foo` was inside the `foo` function itself.  But these comments are probably not a great forum for discussing API design, especially for niggling details in an excellent-looking API.  One more question, though, as it's very cool: where was that in the draft spec?  I hadn't run across that.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Right, the fact that `foo` doesn't refer to the same function (in IE8) is *why* I don't do that. But again, it's not API, it's how I *use* the API in that example (and not in others). The function name thing shows up in about 18 different places because there are so many places it touches. :-) Search for "SetFunctionName" (the abstract op used to set it from various places). But for instance, in the current draft (Nov 8), §12.1.5.8 (property def), §12.13.4 (assignment), §13.2.1.6 (let init), §13.2.2.3 (var init), and a few others.

Answer (score 2):

By using `return manager` you're not using the `this` object you were constructing.  Instead, try this (untested):

```
var Manager = function(name, age, dept) {
    Person.call(this, name, age);
    this.dept = dept; 
    this.mgrDesc = function() {
       return this.desc() + " and I work at the " + this.dept + " department";
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I rather thought it would.

Comment: This is correct **if** you don't use `new Person()` to create `Manager.prototype`. E.g., the bit in your answer is correct, but the bit in the OP's code doing `Manager.prototype = new Person();` is incorrect (a common error).

Comment: Yes, there should probably be an intermediate function in there:  `function F() {}; F.prototype = Person.prototype; Manager.prototype = new F(); Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager` or use some `inherit` function that wraps up this boilerplate.  (Or use your very interesting Lineage library!)

Comment: Oh, I see you updated your answer above with the same info.  Oops.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: :-) Yeah, when I saw your answer I thought "Hmmm, should point this out in code."

Answer (score 0):

```
var Manager, Person, manager,
__hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
__extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor; child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

Person = (function() {
  Person.name = 'Person';

function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.desc = function() {
  return "my name is " + this.name + " I'm " + this.age;
};

return Person;

})();

Manager = (function(_super) {
__extends(Manager, _super);

Manager.name = 'Manager';

function Manager(name, age, dept) {  
this.name = name
this.age = age
this.dept = dept
Manager.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

Manager.prototype.mgrDesc = function() {
  return this.desc() + " and I work at the " + this.dept + " department";
};

return Manager;

})(Person);

manager = new Manager("Foo", 3, "IT");

console.log(manager.mgrDesc());

console.log(manager instanceof Person);

console.log(manager instanceof Manager);
```

=>
my name is Foo I'm 3 and I work at the IT department

true

true

Comment: The other solutions have the advantage that if you later add a method to the Person prototype, the Managers already created would automatically inherit it.  In your technique, they would not.  You've divorced the objects from the usual prototype chain built into the language.

Comment: That was not to say that this is totally incorrect.  There are times when it might be what's wanted.  There are many people promoting similar techniques.  But they work against rather than with the grain of the language.

Comment: class Person
  constructor: (@name, @age) ->
  desc: -> 
    "my name is " + this.name + " I'm " + this.age

class Manager extends Person
  constructor: (@name, @age, @dept) ->
    super
  mgrDesc: -> 
      @.desc() + " and I work at the " + @.dept + " department"


manager = new Manager("Foo", 3, "IT");
console.log(manager.mgrDesc());
console.log(manager instanceof Person);
console.log(manager instanceof Manager);